# pass native object in URL

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, three20

I was following the tutorial [here](http://three20.info/article/2010-10-06-URL-Based-Navigation).

The code I have is:

```
- (void) didSelectObject:(id) object atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*) indexPath    
{
    Group * group = (Group *)((RKMappableObjectTableItem *) object).object;
    [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    group.unread = 0;
    [self.tableView reloadData];

    TTURLAction *action =  [[[TTURLAction actionWithURLPath:@"tt://group"] 
                             applyQuery:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:group forKey:@"kParameterUser"]]
                            applyAnimated:YES];
    [[TTNavigator navigator] openURLAction:action];

}
```

I have set the mapping as:

```
[map from:@"tt://group" toSharedViewController:[TopicsViewController class]];
```

and inside my TopicsViewController I have both tried:

```
- (id) initWithNavigatorURL:(NSURL*)URL query:(NSDictionary*)query {
```

but it didn't work. It's as if it can't find any mapping. Why is this? What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE:**

Here's the updated code based on the suggestion:

```
 TTURLAction *action =  [[[TTURLAction actionWithURLPath:@"tt://group"] 
                                 applyQuery:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:group forKey:@"kParameterUser"]]
                                applyAnimated:YES];
        [[TTNavigator navigator] openURLAction:action];

[map from:@"tt://group?" toSharedViewController:[TopicsViewController class] selector:@selector(initWithNavigationURL:)];

- (id) initWithNavigatorURL:(NSURL*)URL query:(NSDictionary*)query
```

what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not telling it what selector to cal! First, add a `?` to the end of your mapping: @"tt://group?"

When you add any query dictionaries, they are sent like normal params in a url (`?foo=bar&apple=orange`).

Next, if you aren't going to use the selector as part of the URL mapping, use the `from:toSharedViewController:selector:` method to set the selector to the selector you wish to call.

Comment: I actually just want it to call  initWithNavigatorURL:(NSURL*)URL query:(NSDictionary*)query, instead of another selector... saw some other examples and none seem to use that ? .. can you elaborate. even in the three20 documentation I linked on the question above.. it didn't use ?

Comment: Why do you care about the navigatorURL in your init method? why do you need it? Either way, set your selector to be @selector(initWithNavigatorURL:).

Comment: I actually don't care about the navigatorURL, I just care about the object been passed.. Anyway I tried your suggestion and it still doesn't work...

Comment: you are missing the ":" in your selector, and the ? goes in the mapping, not the action

Comment: You have the method name wrong. Your selector is initWithNavigatorURL, not …NavigationURL

Comment: @coneybeare let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1523/discussion-between-adit-and-coneybeare)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know three20 very well, I think however you first need to create an URL to the object you'd like to pass, which can be mapped.

It appears like three20 provides a category on nsobject which allows you to call:
`NSString* url = [myFooObject URLValueWithName:@"barName"];`

This method should be inherited from NSObject by almost any Framework Class.

See *NSObjects to URLs* in the chapter *URL mapping methods* from the tutorial you posted.

Comment: as far as I know... you don't set the URL of the object when we're passing an object as the parameter.. if you set the object's URL, what would be the URL look like in my case?